Is Intraday trading a sin? [Stock Market]
I have been trading the stock market for a long time. I have also incurred losses but now I am making some profit. I wish to earn a specific amount from the stock market, withdraw it and retire early thereby achieving financial independence.
But while executing intraday trades, I incurred many losses. I was forced to sell stocks for a lower price in order to avoid more losses. The moment I place a sell order, the stock is immediately sold and brought by someone, who may sell it for a higher price and make profit.
Now : Isn't this equivalent to feasting one someone's loss? If I trade in this way, won't i accquire karma because I am buying someone's loss and making a profit out of it?
Please help. I seek genuine guidance.
